# Jogging Use in EXTream

Tags: opentext

I am new to EXTream development. I am trying to use Jogging for the first time. Can you help me in knowing the purpose of "Jogging" option in output queue level in OpenTextExtream?

Answer (score 0):

It’s used for offset groups of pages .Offset groups will segregate the pages while printing like customer or banner pages.